# Spark & Drools - How to serialize KieBase with Kryo

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, drools, kryo

I'm running in an Exception trying to serialize a `KieBase` object in Spark.

When I execute the following code:

```
val kieBase = kieContainer.getKieBase
val broadcastKieBase = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(kieBase)
```

A `ConcurrentModificationException` is raised

> Exception in thread "main" com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException:
>   java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Looking around also I found [this is a known problem](https://github.com/cpitman/spark-drools-example/issues/2), but still no solution.

Anyone knows how to serialize a `KieBase` instance with Kryo?

Answer (score 3):

If you are executing the Spark Job with KryoSerializer by setting `.config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")` or it is set to KryoSerializer as a default then please follow below steps :

Create DroolsSerializerRegistration class by extending `org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoRegistrator`. Register class `org.drools.core.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl` for `com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.JavaSerializer` as shown below :

```
package com.spark.kryo.serializers

import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.JavaSerializer
import org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoRegistrator

class DroolsSerializerRegistration extends KryoRegistrator {
    override def registerClasses(kryo: Kryo) {
        kryo.register(classOf[org.drools.core.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl], new JavaSerializer)
   }
}
```

Then set below configuration in SparkConf
`.config("spark.kryo.registrator", "com.spark.kryo.serializers.DroolsSerializerRegistration")`

If you are not sure if this is breaking due to `org.drools.core.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl` then set below configuration in SparkConf to get the exact class causing the issue.
`.config("spark.kryo.registrationRequired", "true")`

In some cases it might give multiple classes then register all classes with `com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.JavaSerializer`.
Once you figure out all classes associated with Drools then remove `spark.kryo.registrationRequired` and register only those classes associated with Drools library and not all which were failed.

Answer (score 1):

i have solved this issue,i use spark-submit run my maven jar as well.
this is my config:

```
.config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializer")
```

Answer (score 0):

KieBase cannot be serializable. Instead create a singleton class and have the KieBase inited in the executor. Each executor will have its own instance.

Comment: KieBase can be successfully serialized using `JavaSerializer`. For example `kryo.register(KieBase.class, new JavaSerializer());` the question is how to do it only with Kryo.